# Should we delete the tag "alfabeto"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Its scope seems excessively limited and, having been applied to a total of six questions so far, the tag [alfabeto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alfabeto) seems unnecessary to me.

Especially as, of these 6 questions, 2 are actually about diacritics ([here](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5495/2764) and [here](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/529/2764)), one about numerals (*algarismos*, [here](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/4961/2764)), and one about names ([here](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/349/2764)), leaving only two questions that carry the tag truly appropriately (about the [name of a letter](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/347/2764), and the presence of ["k", "w" and "y"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/7/2764) in the alphabet).

I'd suggest it's deleted.

Comment: Yes, please. :)

Comment: [Discussion between jacinto and stafusa](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87934/discussion-between-jacinto-and-stafusa).

Comment: I'm with @tchrist: yes, please ;)

Comment: I agree with you. The tag is quite misleading since it can refer to letters, phonemes, etc.

Comment: And yet stafusa and I could not find appropriate, alternative  tags for the question about the two names of the letter g ("uso-de-palavras", "nomes", "diferenças"? well, I think I would delete "diferenças"); For the one about k, w, and y, "ortografia" would do, I think. But I can't think of any new questions for that tag. There might be some existing ones (one about lh, nh, and ch; another about ç). Ok, I'm for deletion, but not before we have a tag for the names of g.

Comment: @Jacinto, I'm for "nomes" and "diferenças-regionais".

Comment: "diferenças-regionais" has three questions now. That's one thing I've often wondered. The asker wonders whether *guê* and *gê* are regional variants. Does this  merit the "diferenças-regionais" tag? Or should it be only for questions that start with a known case of regional differences?

Comment: @Jacinto Let's [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87934/discussion-between-jacinto-and-stafusa) again.

Comment: Ok, I shoulb be back after 5 pm GMT. In the meantime, why don't you edit in a request for alternative tags, especially for the g-question, as the one left there if we remove "alfabeto" ("pronúncia) is not appropriate, or at least enough.

Comment: @Jacinto Used my lunch break. :-) Done.

Comment: Ok. The tag is still in the system though: if you type "al" in the tag box while editing, the system will suggest "alfabeto" with wiki and all. Can we get rid of that @tchrist?

Comment: @Jacinto the tag doesn't exist anymore.